# reading text file with given information

Tags: java, oop, java-io

So I'm trying to turn a text file drinks.txt into a Vending Machine array I can interact with. I'm given the following pieces of code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class VendingMachine {

//data members
private Item[] stock;  //Array of Item objects in machine
private double money;  //Amount of revenue earned by machine

/*********************************************************************
 * This is the constructor of the VendingMachine class that take a
 * file name for the items to be loaded into the vending machine.
 *
 * It creates objects of the Item class from the information in the 
 * file to populate into the stock of the vending machine.  It does
 * this by looping the file to determine the number of items and then
 * reading the items and populating the array of stock. 
 * 
 * @param filename Name of the file containing the items to stock into
 * this instance of the vending machine. 
 * @throws FileNotFoundException If issues reading the file.
 *********************************************************************/
public VendingMachine(String filename) throws FileNotFoundException{
    //Open the file to read with the scanner
    File file = new File(filename);
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);

    //Determine the total number of items listed in the file
    int totalItem = 0;
    while (scan.hasNextLine()){
        scan.nextLine();
        totalItem++;
    } //End while another item in file
    //Create the array of stock with the appropriate number of items
    stock = new Item[totalItem];
    scan.close();

    //Open the file again with a new scanner to read the items
    scan = new Scanner(file);
    int itemQuantity = -1;
    double itemPrice = -1;
    String itemDesc = "";
    int count = 0;
    String line = "";

    //Read through the items in the file to get their information
    //Create the item objects and put them into the array of stock
    while(scan.hasNextLine()){
        line = scan.nextLine();
        String[] tokens = line.split(",");
        try {
            itemDesc = tokens[0];
            itemPrice = Double.parseDouble(tokens[1]);
            itemQuantity = Integer.parseInt(tokens[2]);

            stock[count] = new Item(itemDesc, itemPrice, itemQuantity);
            count++;
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
            System.out.println("Bad item in file " + filename + 
                    " on row " + (count+1) + ".");
        }
    } //End while another item in file
    scan.close();

    //Initialize the money data variable.
    money = 0.0;
} //End VendingMachine constructor

} //End VendingMachine class definition
```

The text files look like this:

```
Milk,2.00,1 
OJ,2.50,6
Water,1.50,10
Soda,2.25,6
Coffee,1.25,4
Monster,3.00,5
```

Overall, I'm just trying to figure out to read the drinks.txt under a VendingMachineDriver class that includes the main method. Do you guys have any advice on how to do this?

Comment: Why do you want to make a text file name into an array?

Comment: The code I'm given automatically turns it into an array already. The array looks somethings like this:                                                                             #  Item   cost    amount left                                                                                                                1  Milk    2.00    3                                                                                                      2  OJ      1.50    6                                                                                               3  Water 3.00    2

Comment: You need to specify the problem in more detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your text file is already converted to the array

```
private Item[] stock;  //Array of Item objects in machine
```

where elements are inserted here

```
stock[count] = new Item(itemDesc, itemPrice, itemQuantity);
```

---

You can either do something with the `stock` array inside the class like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < stock.length; i++) {
    Item item = stock[i];
    // Do something with item
}
```

Or do something with it from outside (you need to create a getter for this)

Inside the class

```
public Item getStockForIndex(int i) {
    return stock[i];
}
```

Where main code is

```
VendingMachine vm = new VendingMachine("filename.txt");

// Get first item
Item item = vm.getStockForIndex(0);

// Do something with item
```

Answer (score 0):

To declare and create a new text file, say with the name "NewTextFile.txt", do this:

```
File newFile=new File("NewTextFile.txt");
```

This creates the text file in the current directory of the project you're working in. The above code also works if you just wanna assign the file in the **newFile** object that already exists in the directory.
Hope this helps you.